# py2exe with multiprocessing fails to run the processes

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, py2exe

I am using Python 2.6 over windows 7 and I am trying to use multiprocess:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=(SOME_ARGS))
p.start()
p.join()
```

while I run the code from CMD (using the interpreter) everything works fine, but after I  create an exe file with py2exe, the execution of the process fails with the following error:

**error: no such option: --multiprocessing-fork**

all the solutions I found did not help.
any ideas?

Comment: nope, I saw that and tried to use this solution. The problem there is that another "main" window pops. This is not the case here. The only thing I have is this error message.

Comment: actually you were right.. the changes were not saved at the location I worked, now I checked it again and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know you are using a app of year 2008? (py2exe), python is in constant actualizations, and then gives problems with py2exe, I can give you a better solution...

You can use cxfreeze: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Simply, easy, good, and actualized.

I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 5):

You need a call to `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` when packaging a Python script into an executable for use on Windows. This call should come just after `if __name__ == '__main__':` before actually calling `main()`

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a great link](http://japrogbits.blogspot.com/2010/03/multiprocessing-py2exe-and-windows.html) that explains how to freeze your multiprocessing program to make it work with py2exe:

Namely, you will need to call `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` right after your call to main:

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```