# Launch a process completely independent of the launching process

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe, python-multiprocessing, cherrypy

Hello I have a gui application, a simple painting program, written with PyQt 4, Python 2.7 and running on Windows, below is an excerpt

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    paint_app=main_paint_editor()#instantiate the gui
    paint_app.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This gets the gui  started as a main thread. Once the UI is up and running  there's a button that is supposed to launch a Flask app, (CherryPy )

This is done via a signal-slot connection in the gui, i.e

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(my_webserver_button,QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"),lauch_the_server)
```

The function launch_the_server, is meant to start a separate process for the flask app. As there is no real dependency between the gui and the flask app, I really want to use a separate process and not threads.
Also while experimenting, the use of threads in this specific case makes my paint gui stutter. So a separate process is my goal.

In order to start the webserver and flask app in its own proccess I have

```
from cherrpy import wsgiserver
from multiprocessing import Process

def launch_the_server(self):
    flask_process=Process(target=start_cherrypy, name="local_webserver")
    flask_process.start()
    flask_process.join()

def start_cherrypy(self):
    localwsgi_server=wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('localhost',1234),flask_app,numthreads=10,server_name="paintserver")
    localwsgi_server.start()
```

when I run in debug mode using eclipse, this works fine. I get a separate process and the flask application works fine.
However when I build an executable of my entire application using py2exe,
it doesn't work at all. 
I do get an application which runs, however when I try and launch the web-server nothing happens. I put a couple of debug messages in the exe and none get printed.

I thought it might be a cherrypy problem at first so I replaced the code with something simple, i.e launching a process that simply writes "hello" to a text file
Nothing happened in the executable though it worked fine from Eclipse debugger.

How can I launch a separate process from within an existing GUI application to run additional functions such as starting a flask app? or writing text to a text file?

Comment: Are you seeking for a double fork?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing problem \[pyqt, py2exe\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073942/multiprocessing-problem-pyqt-py2exe)

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me.

[py2exe-with-multiprocessing-fails-to-run-the-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514031/py2exe-with-multiprocessing-fails-to-run-the-processes)

Mainly the

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

did the trick looks like it was more a quirk of py2exe. Thanks to everyone for looking